# Slashes show up with the colour purple while using the Rich Printing module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use the `Rich` module's `print` function, when I print a forwards slash, it prints out as a forwards slash with PURPLE. How can I fix this???

I'm trying to make a terminal game, and this really ticks me off because all of my ASCII have ugly purple slashes that do not fit in with the colour.

This is my code:

```
from rich.console import Console
con = Console()
con.print("(ASCII)", justify="center")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the text you're trying print? Can we see a screenshot maybe?

Comment: @ThaerA https://ibb.co/LzjNJCV is the link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich is highlighting slashes as paths. You can disable highlighting by setting  `highlight=False` on `con.print`. See the docs on [highlighting](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/highlighting.html).